# emacs lsp c-mode: Command "clangd" is not present on the path

Tags: emacs, clang, clangd, emacs-lsp

I want to use Emacs LSP c-mode, but I'm getting the error 'Command "clangd" is not present on the path'.

I did the following steps to install:

1. Get lsp package from melpa-stable
2. Get company-lsp from melpa-stable
3. Get ccls using homebrew
4. Add the following to my .emacs file:

   (require 'lsp-mode)
   (add-hook 'rust-mode-hook #'lsp)
   (add-hook 'c-mode-hook #'lsp)
   (require 'company-lsp)
   (push 'company-lsp company-backends)

I have installed llvm (which should include clang) using homebrew and added its path as an environment variable.

Does anybody know why I get this error?

Comment: How exactly have you "added its path as an environment variable"

Comment: Added 'export PATH=/usr/local/opt/llvm/bin:$PATH' to my .bash_profile file.

Comment: Look at `exec-path` and `(getenv "PATH")` in Emacs.  If they don't have your directory, then you're not adding it in a way that Emacs is seeing it.  You can simply add it to `exec-path` and it will probably work (`exec-path` is initialized from `$PATH` at start up; usually `$PATH` isn't used after start up in Emacs).

Comment: I got this to work today on Linux (Debian 10).  In my emacs file I had to add: (setq lsp-clients-clangd-executable "/usr/lib/llvm-9/bin/clangd"). Maybe you need to do something like that.

Comment: I recommend confirming that you've got clangd.

Comment: Windows, Linux or MacOS? It matters. In Linux/MacOS typing `which clang` returns the full path of the executable, in CMD you must use `where` and `Get-Command` in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

I have just managed to set it up.

The problem is that on os x your environmental variables are not imported correctly when using GUI emacs.
In particular, if you try [evaluating](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html) in your emacs

```
(getenv "PATH")
```

you will get a different output from what you get by running

```
echo $PATH
```

in your terminal.

I have solved this by installing [exec-path-from-shell](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18393068/4345594).

Finally, double check (even though you've mentioned, you've done this) that not only have you installed llvm, but also correctly added it to your path, by running

```
brew install llvm
ln -s "$(brew --prefix llvm)/bin/clangd" "/usr/local/bin/clangd"
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53380855/4345594)